# Script, which used to work, now fails every time with "We're sorry, a server error occurred. Please wait a bit and try again."

Tags: google-apps-script

My Google script has suddenly stopped working, despite no changes being made to it. It's a very simple script that takes a URL, downloads the page and returns the HTML. I've been using it for months without any problems but yesterday it just stopped working. The output of the script is now an error message: "We're sorry, a server error occurred. Please wait a bit and try again." I've waited and tried again but whatever the issue is doesn't seem to be going away. Has Google changed anything recently that would cause this to stop working?

Here's the full script:

```
function doGet(e) {
    var url = e.queryString || "";
    if (url != "") {
        return getPage(url);
    }  
    return "not found";
}

function getPage(url) {
    var options = {
        headers : {'Cache-Control' : 'max-age=0'}
    };
    var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options);
    var html = response.getContentText();

    // Here I have tried logging the returned HTML and also emailing it
    // to myself and in both cases I see what's expected; the correct
    // HTML for the requested page. Is the error on the line below?

    return HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(html);
}
```

What's wrong?

(There are many other questions asking about this error message but I don't see any that appear to have the same cause, except perhaps that my script was valid but Google has changed something and it is no longer valid.)

Answer: Change the last line of the `getPage` function to `return HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(html).setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.IFRAME);`.

Comment: Did you try putting things in the try-catch block and logging the errors, if any?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems that there's an issue with the HtmlService sandbox mode. The default was NATIVE (since Feb. 2014), but for some reason, since yesterday, if defaults to EMULATED which is pretty cripple. There's a thread on [Google code‌](https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=4866)​ that discusses this issue, maybe that's the thing.

P.S

Seems that Chrome v.41 doesn't suffer from this issue, so I'd recommend you try to update your Chrome before making any changes to your code.